# Analyzing function memory and CPU usage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, sfml

I am making a video game, which is a pretty small 2D shooter. Recently I noticed that the frame rate drops dramatically when there are about 9 bullets in the scene or more. My laptop can handle advanced 3D games and my game is very very simple so hardware should not be a problem.

So now I have a very big code (at least for one person) and I am pretty confused where I should look for? there are too many functions and classes related to bullets, and for example, I don't know how to analyze if the rendering function has problems or the update function? I could use MVS 2015 debugging tools for other programs, but for a game, it is not practical, for example, if I put a breakpoint before the render function, It should be checked 60 times in a second plus I can't input anything so I will never have bullets to test render function! I tried to use task manager, and I realized that CPU usage goes up really fast for each bullet, but when the game slows down only 10 percent of the CPU is used!

So my questions are:

- How can I analyze functions when I can't use debugging tool?
- And why game slows down while it still can use system resources?

Comment: What you need to do is some [*profiling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). That way you can see which of your functions take the most time or are called the most times, and you can then start looking at them for optimizations. Though it seems like you have a good start since you know it must be related to the "bullets".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see what part consumes most of the processing power, you should use a function [profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)). It doesn't "debug", but it creates a report when it's finished.

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) is a good tool for that.

Why the game slows down? Depends on your implementation. I can create a program that divides two numbers and make it take 5 minutes to calculate the result.

Comment: Visual Studio has it's own heap and CPU profilers, but they might not be available in the community version, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I think you're right. But I never used it. Usually I develop my Windows programs to be cross-platform exactly for this reason. I debug and profile on Linux for free.

Comment: I am not new to C++, but most of the books I have read are about how to write good code, There are rare pieces of advice about using debugging tools, Is there a reference or tutorial on debugging and analyzing?

Comment: @shayan Honestly, I haven't learned this from a book. I learned by doing. Try it and learn by doing. There are tons of tutorials online.

Comment: I am not asking why the game is slow, but why it does not use more CPU resources while it can?

Comment: @shayan I understand, but ironically, my answer still applies. Think of `sleep` commands. It all depends on your implementation. You will never, ever find a single answer to this question.

Comment: @Shayan good code is really a matter of perspective to be honest, your book may claim to be about writing good code but that doesn't mean it is a good book on how to write good code.  In regards to your post about why doesn't it use more CPU resources while it can, did you develop it to be multi-threaded?  Programs don't automatically detect how much CPU resources are available and just take from it unless you develop your game to do that.

Comment: @Shayan A-lot of these advanced 3D games take advantage of several features such as off-loading work onto their GPU as well, using things such as a Compute shader, and even do their own load balancing on your CPU in order for them to take up the resources, these features didn't just come with the program, but had to be developed into the application.

Comment: Instead of using Valgrind I used very sleepy, and the most CPU consuming function, is a function named "RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification" which uses about 80 percent of total CPU the program uses. My worst function only uses 0.02% of total CPU. Now what should I do?

Comment: @shayan I'm not familiar with that library, unfortunately. Refer to the documentation of that library, experts or start a new question on startoverflow *after* you have researched a lot about this issue and this function.

Answer (score 1):

We're in the video-game industry as well and we use a very simple tool on PC for CPU profiling: very sleepy.

http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/

It is simple, but really helped me out a lot of times. Just fire up the program from IDE and let very sleepy run for a few thousand samples and off you go!

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? The site does not really describe how it works. What are the meanings of exclusive and inclusive?

Comment: Inclusive are the timings including all potential calls to subroutines. Exclusive is the time spent in only that routine. E.g., an `update` routine might spend 50% of your frame-time, inclusive, yet the routine itself most probably contains a few calls to different routines. So exclusive it might be only just a few %.

Comment: I tested to game, and There are 3 functions that use the most CPU resources. RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification for 79% Exclusive is on top. The most CPU consuming function I have written only consumes 0.02% Exclusive... What clue this is giving to me?

Comment: That you need to figure out what `RtlSubscribeWnfStateChangeNotification ` is and why it is consuming so much time. It'd start with finding the callstack to that function. It must be called somewhere in your code. Try to locate that and see what happens exactly.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to memory holes, Valgrind is a good tool, as already noted by The Quantum Physicist.
For timing, I would write my own small tracing/profiling tool (if my IDE does not already have one). Use a text debugging output to write short messages to a log file. Something like that:

```
void HandleBullet() {
    printf("HandleBullet START: %i", GetSysTime());
    // do your function stuff
    printf("HandleBullet END: %i", GetSysTime()); // or calculate time of function directly
}
```

Write those debugging messages in all of the functions where you think they could take too long.
After some execution time, you can look into that file and see if something obvious happened (blocking somewhere).
If not, use a high level language of your choice to write a small parser for your created log file to tidy up and analyze your output. Calculate stuff like overall time spent in some function, or chart which functions took the longest. Should not be too difficult, if you stick to a log message style which is easy parsable for you.